# Manually exit a temporary overlay map

Tags: emacs, closures, elisp, key-bindings

In emacs 24, `set-temporary-overlay-map` makes active a keymap which becomes inactivated as soon as the user presses a key which is not defined in that keymap.

I need to inactivate the overlay keymap manually, but no function is provided to do this in particular. I've peeked into the source code:

```
(defun set-temporary-overlay-map (map &optional keep-pred)
  "Set MAP as a temporary keymap taking precedence over most other keymaps.
Note that this does NOT take precedence over the \"overriding\" maps
`overriding-terminal-local-map' and `overriding-local-map' (or the
`keymap' text property).  Unlike those maps, if no match for a key is
found in MAP, the normal key lookup sequence then continues.

Normally, MAP is used only once.  If the optional argument
KEEP-PRED is t, MAP stays active if a key from MAP is used.
KEEP-PRED can also be a function of no arguments: if it returns
non-nil then MAP stays active."
  (let* ((clearfunsym (make-symbol "clear-temporary-overlay-map"))
         (overlaysym (make-symbol "t"))
         (alist (list (cons overlaysym map)))
         (clearfun
          ;; FIXME: Use lexical-binding.
          `(lambda ()
             (unless ,(cond ((null keep-pred) nil)
                            ((eq t keep-pred)
                             `(eq this-command
                                  (lookup-key ',map
                                              (this-command-keys-vector))))
                            (t `(funcall ',keep-pred)))
               (set ',overlaysym nil)   ;Just in case.
               (remove-hook 'pre-command-hook ',clearfunsym)
               (setq emulation-mode-map-alists
                     (delq ',alist emulation-mode-map-alists))))))
    (set overlaysym overlaysym)
    (fset clearfunsym clearfun)
    (add-hook 'pre-command-hook clearfunsym)
    ;; FIXME: That's the keymaps with highest precedence, except for
    ;; the `keymap' text-property ;-(
    (push alist emulation-mode-map-alists)))
```

I gather that the mechanism to inactivate the current overlay keymap is as follows:

1. A function `clearfun` is defined to run before every command, checking if the previous command  invoked was in the map.
2. If it was not in the map, the following code is executed:

(Why doesn't this format correctly? Ok, now it does)

```
(set ',overlaysym nil)   ;Just in case.
               (remove-hook 'pre-command-hook ',clearfunsym)
               (setq emulation-mode-map-alists
                     (delq ',alist emulation-mode-map-alists))
```

Thus, what I really want is to execute the code above with the appropriate variables. But this code is part of a closure, and I'm having trouble determining values like `overlaysym`, `clearfunsym`, `alist` inside the closure. I tried looking for `clearfunsym` by `eval`-ing `pre-command-hook`, but strangely nothing is there  (except for another unrelated hook).

I tried re-evaluating the function defintion and edebugging it, and I notcied after the `(add-hook 'pre-command-hook clearfunsym)`, `pre-command-hook` is still `nil`, which puzzles me. I will continue digging deeper into the source code, and maybe I will just rewrite my own version of this function to additionally produce a `force-clear` function that I can call later, but maybe someone can see a cleaner solution.

Comment: Great question(s). Expecting interesting & informative answer(s) from @Stefan (or perhaps someone else). Looking forward to learning more about this, myself.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "I need to inactivate the overlay keymap manually".

Comment: I did also not quite understand how erjoalgo wants to "Manually exit a temporary overlay map". It should be quite simple. Just press a key that is not in the temporary keymap. The only problem I see is the case that all keys are put into the temporary keymap. But, I think that is not the intented use.

Comment: Currently the only way to exit the keymap is by having the user press a key outside of that keymap. I need to be able to deactivate the keymap upon an arbitrary condition. For example, if the user presses a certain key inside the keymap.

Comment: Okay, then just look at my answer. There is everything you need.

Comment: I will definitely look at your answer.

Comment: @Stefan
By the way, I am sorry if my intended usage was unclear. I realize this might not be obvious, so here are some examples:

1. I define a menu-keymap which needs to read more than one key, so I use the `set-temporary-overlay` with KEEP-PRED to `t`. But I want to provide the user a way to just exit the map (note that pressing a key outside key will execute whatever command was bound for that key. Eg, if I want the user to be able to exit my map by pressing `q`, if `q` is not defined in my map, not only will inactivate it (desired), but also`self-insert` command will be called (undesired)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote: "I'm having trouble determining values like overlaysym"
But, overlaysym is evaluated. It has the value (make-symbol "t").
It is a symbol with name t. This makes it hard to access it but not impossible.
Evaluation of the following lines gives the out-commented results:

```
(setq mysym (make-symbol "t"))
;; t
(set mysym 'test)
;; test
(symbol-value mysym)
;; test
```

The same applies to clearfunsym which evaluates to clear-temporary-overlay-map.

One more comment: When you debug set-temporary-overlay-map you are hitting keys. Might it be that these keystrokes call clear-temporary-overlay-map and clear pre-command-hook?

Try that:

```
(defadvice set-temporary-overlay-map (after test activate)
  (setq test-pre-command-hook pre-command-hook))
```

Then enter text-scale-mode (C-+) and look at test-pre-command-hook. For an istance evaluating `test-pre-command-hook` on my computer gave me the following list:

(**clear-temporary-overlay-map** tooltip-hide).

Let us do the same with `emulation-mode-map-alists`. Then we get:

```
(((t keymap (67108912 . #[0 "\301\302\300!!\207" [1 text-scale-adjust abs] 3 "
...

(fn)" nil]) (45 . #[0 "\301\302\300!!\207" [1 text-scale-adjust abs] 3 "
(fn)" nil]))))
```

Especially, note the **`t`** at the beginning. That means you find the overlay map by searching for the list with symbol `t` at the beginning.

Something like the following code fragment should be sufficient to delete the overlay map:

```
(when (assoc-string "t" (car emulation-mode-map-alists))
  (setq emulation-mode-map-alists (cdr emulation-mode-map-alists)))
```

The `when` is just a protection. (Maybe, something else has killed the map before?) The temporary map should always be at the front (because of the `push` in `set-temporary-overlay-map`). Does anything have a chance to put another keymap in front of it? Maybe, something time-controlled? Then you would need to search `emulation-mode-map-alists` for the alist with the `(make-symbol "t")` keymap.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and I'm sorry I couldn't look at it earlier. I ended up rewriting this function to do away with the hacks and lack of readability, and additionally to provide the user a nice `force-overlay-clear`, which clears the current overlay if it exists. I will let some time pass in order to allow possible discussion of the problem and solutions provided.

Answer (score 0):

The original `set-temporary-overlay-map` is very confusing, unreadable, and relies on a lot of unnecessary dirty hacks and tricks. Using lexical binding, I have rewritten the function in a way that is more clear and modular.

1. The revised function uses lexical-binding to replace the eager-lazy evaluation hacks (in this case they are completely unnecessary).
2. The original function unnecessarily creates two symbols for each function, (`clearfunsym` and `clear-fun` are basically the same thing, the later being used only as the function cell of the former)
3. The revised function provides an `force-overlay-clear`, which is called by the `clear-temporary-overlay-map` pre-command-hook when the conditions are met (ie, that the last key was not in the overlay map). It can also be called by the user if he wants to manually clear this map. The function voids `force-overlay-clear`'s own function cell, so it will err if called twice.
4. Code to test whether clear is applicable simplified.

I was not able to do away with the extremely weird `(overlaysym (make-symbol "t"))`, fearing that some other code might rely on this `t` symbol. Thus, the revised version is almost certainly equivalent to the original version. I have tested this, and it works nicely.

```
(defun set-temporary-overlay-map (map &optional keep-pred)
  (lexical-let* (
   (map map)
   (keep-pred keep-pred)
   (clear-temporary-overlay-map  nil)
   (force-overlay-clear nil)
   (overlaysym (make-symbol "t"))
   (alist (list (cons overlaysym map))))

    (fset 'force-overlay-clear (lambda ()
          (message "clearing overlay")              
          ;this is a copy of the original code to clear
          (set overlaysym nil)   ;Just in case.
          (remove-hook 'pre-command-hook 'clear-temporary-overlay-map)
          (setq emulation-mode-map-alists
          (delq alist emulation-mode-map-alists))
          ;void the function cell of 'force-overlay-clear', an attempt to clear overlay twice will err
          (fset 'force-overlay-clear nil)
    ))
   (fset 'clear-temporary-overlay-map (lambda ()
          (unless (cond
         ((null keep-pred) nil)
         (keep-pred
          (lookup-key map (this-command-keys-vector)))
         (t (funcall keep-pred)))
      (force-overlay-clear)
      )))

    (set overlaysym overlaysym)
    (add-hook 'pre-command-hook 'clear-temporary-overlay-map)
    ;; FIXME: That's the keymaps with highest precedence, except for
    ;; the `keymap' text-property ;-
    (push alist emulation-mode-map-alists))
  )
```

Comment: @Drew, Stefan I've seen that you are both pretty active in these topics, so maybe you have some comments about this.

Comment: `fset` changes the definition of that symbol globally, so it will break miserably when two `set-temporary-overlay-map` are used at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
(defun my-exit-command ()
  (do-what-the-q-key-should-do))

....(set-temporary-overlay-map
     my-overlay-map
     (lambda ()
       (and (eq this-command (lookup-key my-overlay-map
                                         (this-single-command-keys)))
            (not (eq this-command 'my-exit-command)))))
....
```